# How to generate mean-preserving orthonormal matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, orthogonal

I want to generate random **mean-preserving** ***orthonormal*** matrix **A** in MATLAB, such that :

A*trans(A) = I,  &&  A*1=1  (**1** is the vector in which all arrays equal 1)

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because "try math.stackexchange"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4575590

They proposed the following function:

```
function [U] = genU(m)
V1 = ones(m, 1) / sqrt(m);
[V, L] = svd(V1);
[Rm1, tmp] = qr(randn(m - 1, m - 1));
U = V * blkdiag(1, Rm1) * V';
```

Where **m** is the desired dimension.